# How to mask with 3d array and 2d array numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How do you select a group of elements from a 3d array using a 1d array.

```
#These are my 3 data types
# A = numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[float]]
# B1 = numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[float]]]
#B2=numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[float]]]
#I want to choose values from A based on values from B1 in the B2
```

This is what I tried but it returned all `False`:

```
A2[i]=image_values[updated_image_values==initial_means[i]]
```

Example:

```
A=[[1,1,1][2,2,2]]
B=[[[1,1,1],[2,3,4]],[[2,2,2],[1,1,1]],[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]]
B2=[[[2,2,2],[9,3,21]],[[22,0,-2],[-1,-1,1]],[[1,-1,-1],[10,0,2]]]

#A2 is calculated as the means of the B2 values that correspond 
#to it's value according to B
```

So, to calculate `A2` we use check what values in B2 are equal to values in A. So, for the first index `A[0]`, `B[0][0]`,`B[1][1]` and `B[2][0]` are equal to `A[0]`. So for `A2[0]`, we get the corresponding values of `B` in `B2` and use those to calculate the average for each index:

```
#A2[0][0]=(B2[0][0][0]+B2[1][1][0]+B2[2][0][0]) /3 = 0.67

#A2[1][2]=(B2[1][0][2]+B2[2][1][2]) /2 = 0

#After doing this for every A2 value, A2 should be:

A2=[[0.67,0,0.67],[16,0,0]]
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on how to got those `A2` values? Some pseudo code even?

Comment: Sure. I did it manually cause I couldn't figure out the pseudo code but I'm putting an explanation up

Comment: Yes, adding in those manual calculations would help too.

Comment: Explained it. Hopefully it makes it a little clearer

Comment: How do `A` and `B` feature in the manual calculations of `A2` ?

Comment: Added some more of an explanation :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach with [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
idx = np.argwhere((B == A[:,None,None]).all(-1))
B2_indexed = B2[idx[:,1],idx[:,2]]
_,start, count = np.unique(idx[:,0],return_index=1,return_counts=1)
out = np.add.reduceat(B2_indexed,start)/count.astype(float)[:,None]
```

Alternatively, we can save on memory a bit by avoiding creating `4D` mask with a `3D` mask instead for getting `idx`, like so -

```
dims = np.maximum(B.max(axis=(0,1)),A.max(0))+1
A_reduced = np.ravel_multi_index(A.T,dims)
B_reduced = np.ravel_multi_index(B.T,dims)
idx = np.argwhere(B_reduced.T == A_reduced[:,None,None])
```

Here's another approach with one-loop -

```
out = np.empty(A.shape)
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    r,c = np.where((B == A[i]).all(-1))    
    out[i] = B2[r,c].mean(0)
```