# Mask a three dimensional array to perform segmentation

Tags: python, image-processing, mask, numpy-ndarray, feature-extraction

I'm working with Python. I want to know if there is a python way to mask a 3d array XYZ (volumetric image) to perform a segmentation analysis such as skeletonization.

I'm handling a 600x600x300 array so reducing the number of candidates to be analyzed is key to performance. I tried np.array[mask] but the array dimension changes to 1. The where method such as this [How to Correctly mask 3D Array with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752314/how-to-correctly-mask-3d-array-with-numpy) performs the change to one value at the time, but skeletonization needs to analyze the neighbors to be performed.

Edit: This is something simple but it might help you to get the idea. It's to create a 3d AOI inside a volume.

```
# create array with random numbers
Array = np.random.random([10, 10,10])

# create a boolean mask of zeros
maskArr=np.zeros_like(Array, dtype=bool)

# set a few values in the mask to true
maskArr[1:8,1:5,1:3] = 1

# Try to analise the data with mask
process= morphology.skeletonize(Array[maskArr])
```

this is the error due to the 1-d array:

> ValueError: skeletonize requires a 2D or 3D image as input, got 1D.

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem. Have you tried multiplying the mask and the volume elementwise?

Comment: I tried your solution and it reduced the time to perform the analysis, but I don't know if it could d be improved the ways to tackle this problem. I started with a 2d array with the tuples, but I decided to create a boolean mask array to avoid scanning a list. I will try to create a small code to explain.

Comment: You cannot create images of arbitrary shape, it has to be a rectangle. So extracting the pixels masked cannot preserve neighborhood information by definition. But what you can do is find the bounding box of your mask and extract that. You should get a smaller image.

Comment: you can think of it as a 2d images stacked one on top of the other as slices, like a CT scan. I don't want to extract a new volume, just to mask or create an AOI inside the volume avoiding the analysis over other areas for performance. imagine a complete volume of a human head and I just want to analyze one eye without cropping.